# Unknown exception error while opening edge using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am getting this error as trying to open microsoft edge with selenium webdriver. this is with latest RS4 win10(17121) and webdriver(17110). Python 3.4

Tried with older report's solution but still facing the same issue.

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):   File "fishbowl.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()   File "fishbowl.py", line 24, in main
    driver=webdriver.Edge();   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 43, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 208, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error
```